# how to put a profile image and a searchbar in a toolbar?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I am new to Android development I am building an app but from last three days, I am stuck while making toolbar I am very confused. I want to make toolbar like this
[image: in this toolbar the title and image will be set through code in java file when user will login]

[image: when search icon is pressed then this toolbar should change like this]

[image: and when back button is pressed then again this view appear in toolbar]

Answer (score 0):

The widget elements in your design are the following from left to right:

Navigation Drawer Indicator

ImageView

SearchView

Toggle

Overflow Menu

These can all be implemented using default widgets. It is not common to put a profile image to the right of the title, but you could do this by putting a custom layout inside the toolbar view.

It is also not common to place a toggle in the action bar, but it is possible using an ActionLayout.